# Swiftui - Need to spin the selected button only

Tags: button, swiftui

I am following the 100 days of swift course in Hackingwithswift (https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/animation-wrap-up).  Project 6 challenge 1 requests "Go back to the Guess the Flag project and add some animation: When you tap the correct flag, make it spin around 360 degrees on the Y axis".
I was able to make the buttons spin when the correct answer is selected but I do not know how to make only the selected button spin.

This is the loop that created the buttons:

```
 ForEach(0..<3){ number in
                
                Button(action:{
                    self.flagTapped(number)
                }){
                    FlagImage(number: number, countries: self.countries)
                }
                .rotation3DEffect(.degrees(self.animationAmount), axis: (x: 0, y: 1, z: 0))
                }
```

This the flagTapped function:

```
 func flagTapped(_ number: Int){
    if number == correctAswer{
        scoreTitle = "Correct"
        self.score += 1
        withAnimation() {
            self.animationAmount += 360
        }
    }
    else{
        scoreTitle = "Wrong. That is the flag of \(self.countries[number])"
        self.score -= 1
    }
    showingMessage = true
}
```

Thanks for any help

I am posting the whole code in hopes of having an answer that makes the second suggested option to work

```
 struct ContentView: View {

@State private var countries = ["Estonia","France","Germany","Ireland","Italy","Nigeria","Poland","Russia","Spain","UK","US"].shuffled()

@State private var correctAnswer = Int.random(in: 0...2)

@State private var showingMessage = false
@State private var scoreTitle = ""
@State private var score = 0

@State private var animationAmount = 0.0

var body: some View {
    
    ZStack{
        LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.blue,.black]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        VStack (spacing:30){
            VStack{
                Text("Tap the flag of")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                Text(countries[correctAnswer])
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .fontWeight(.black)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            }
            
            ForEach(0 ..< 3) { number in
                
                if number == self.correctAnswer {
                    Button(action: {
                        self.flagTapped(number)
                    }) {
                        FlagImage(number: number, countries: self.countries)
                    }
                    .rotation3DEffect(.degrees(self.animationAmount), axis: (x: 0, y: 1, z: 0))
                } else {
                    Button(action: {
                        self.flagTapped(number)
                    }) {
                        FlagImage(number: number, countries: self.countries)
                    }
                    .rotation3DEffect(.degrees(self.animationAmount), axis: (x: 1, y: 0, z: 0))
                }
            }
            Text("Your score is \(score)")
                .foregroundColor(.white)
            Spacer()
        }
    }
    .alert(isPresented: $showingMessage){
        Alert(title: Text(scoreTitle), message: Text(""), dismissButton: .default(Text("Continue")){
            self.askQuestion()
        })
    }
}

func flagTapped(_ number: Int){
    if number == correctAnswer{
        scoreTitle = "Correct"
        self.score += 1
        withAnimation() {
            self.animationAmount += 360
        }
    }
    else{
        scoreTitle = "Wrong. That is the flag of \(self.countries[number])"
        self.score -= 1
        withAnimation() {
            self.animationAmount += 360
        }
    }
    showingMessage = true
}

func askQuestion(){
    countries.shuffle()
    correctAnswer = Int.random(in: 0...2)
}
}

struct FlagImage: View {
var number: Int
var countries:[String]=[]

var body: some View {
    Image(countries[number])
    .renderingMode(.original)
    .clipShape(Capsule())
    .overlay(Capsule().stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 1))
    .shadow(color: .black, radius: 2)
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are applying the `.rotation3DEffect` to every button, but the animation doesn't happen until you change `self.animationAmount`.

You can only use `self.animationAmount` for the `correctAnswer`:

Change:

```
.rotation3DEffect(.degrees(self.animationAmount), axis: (x: 0, y: 1, z: 0))
```

to:

```
.rotation3DEffect(.degrees(number == correctAnswer ? self.animationAmount : 0), axis: (x: 0, y: 1, z: 0))
```

---

The other way to do it is: (alas, this only seems to work in Xcode 12b5):

```
ForEach(0 ..< 3) { number in
    if number == correctAnswer {
        Button(action: {
            self.flagTapped(number)
        }) {
            FlagImage(number: number, countries: self.countries)
        }
        .rotation3DEffect(.degrees(self.animationAmount), axis: (x: 0, y: 1, z: 0))
    } else {
        Button(action: {
            self.flagTapped(number)
        }) {
            FlagImage(number: number, countries: self.countries)
        }
    }
}
```

This seems less satisfying because of the repetition of the `Button` code, but it could be handy if you wish to apply different animations to the non-selected buttons.

---

**The problem with the code in Xcode 11.6**

The problem with the code that Xcode 11.6 was having is really a problem that you'll encounter with SwiftUI repeatedly unless you are careful and do things the right way.

When you are creating a list of views with `ForEach`, it is very important that SwiftUI be able to uniquely identify the items.  In the original code, we were using `ForEach(0..<3)` and those are horrible `ids` because they don't change when the flags change.

To fix the problem, the best thing to do is to use `ForEach` with an array of `Identifiable` items (items that have a unique `id`).

I replaced the array of country names with an array of `Flag`.  `Flag` is a `struct` which has a unique `id` and the `country` name.  Also, `Flag` conforms to `Identifiable` (which means it supplies a unique `id`).  Because the items are identifiable, we can just do `ForEach(countries.prefix(3))` to show the flags of the first 3 countries.  And because the flags are `Identifiable`, when the array changes, the view will definitely be redrawn correctly.

Take a look at the changes I have made.  Note that I added an additional animation that causes the wrong flags to fade away while the right one spins.  It was necessary to restore the `opacity` settings when starting a new game, or else the flags would still be invisible.

```
struct FlagImage: View {
    var country: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Image(country)
            .renderingMode(.original)
            .clipShape(Capsule())
            .overlay(Capsule().stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 1))
            .shadow(color: .black, radius: 2)
    }
}

struct Flag: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let country: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showingScore = false
    @State private var scoreTitle = ""
    
    @State private var countries = ["Estonia", "France", "Germany", "Ireland", "Italy", "Nigeria", "Poland", "Russia", "Spain", "UK", "US"].shuffled().map(Flag.init)
    @State private var correctAnswer = Int.random(in: 0...2)
    @State private var score = 0
    @State private var alertMessage = ""
    @State private var animationAmount = 0.0
    @State private var animatedOpacity = 1.0
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
                LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.blue, .black]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            VStack {
                VStack {
                    Text("Tap the flag of ").foregroundColor(.white)
                    Text("\(countries[correctAnswer].country) ")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .fontWeight(.black)
                }
                
                ForEach(countries.prefix(3)) { flag in
                    Group {
                        if flag.country == self.countries[self.correctAnswer].country {
                            Button(action: {
                                self.flagTapped(flag.country)
                            }) {
                                FlagImage(country: flag.country)
                            }
                            .rotation3DEffect(.degrees(self.animationAmount), axis: (x: 0, y: 1, z: 0))
                        } else {
                            Button(action: {
                                self.flagTapped(flag.country)
                            }) {
                                FlagImage(country: flag.country)
                            }
                            .opacity(self.animatedOpacity)
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                Text("Score: \(score)").foregroundColor(.white)
                
                Spacer()
            }
        }
        .alert(isPresented: $showingScore) {
            Alert(title: Text(scoreTitle), message: Text(alertMessage), dismissButton: .default(Text("Continue")) {
                self.askQuestion()
            })
        }
    }
    
    func flagTapped(_ country: String) {
        if country == countries[correctAnswer].country {
            score += 1
            scoreTitle = "Correct!"
            alertMessage = "Your score is now \(score)"
            withAnimation {
                animationAmount += 360
                animatedOpacity = 0
            }
        } else {
            scoreTitle = "Wrong."
            alertMessage = "That is the flag of \(country)"
            score -= 1
        }
        
        showingScore = true
    }
    
    func askQuestion() {
        countries.shuffle()
        correctAnswer = Int.random(in: 0...2)
        self.animatedOpacity = 1.0
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

---

**The minimal fix for your code:**

Now that I have identified why this wasn't working in Xcode 11.6, here are the minimal changes to make to your code to make it work:

1. Change the `ForEach` loop to iterate over an `Array` of tuples that contain `(offset, element)` and use the country name as the `id` by adding `, id: \.element`.  Since the country names are unique, this serves the purpose of ensuring the flags update when they change.
2. In the closure, select the parts of the tuple and call them `number` and `name` for clarity.
3. Put the `if` statement with the buttons inside of a `Group { }` because SwiftUI in Xcode 11.6 can't handle the `if` by itself.

```
    ForEach(Array(self.countries.prefix(3).enumerated()), id: \.element) { number, name in
        Group {
            if number == self.correctAnswer {
                Button(action: {
                    self.flagTapped(number)
                }) {
                    FlagImage(number: number, countries: self.countries)
                }
                .rotation3DEffect(.degrees(self.animationAmount), axis: (x: 0, y: 1, z: 0))
            } else {
                Button(action: {
                    self.flagTapped(number)
                }) {
                    FlagImage(number: number, countries: self.countries)
                }
                .rotation3DEffect(.degrees(self.animationAmount), axis: (x: 1, y: 0, z: 0))
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The second option does not work as intended. I would like it to work but I don't know what is wrong. It does not animate the buttons anymore. I addition, the flags are not reloaded (The screen always shows the same flags)

Comment: I just posted the whole code. Could you take a look at it? Thanks!

Comment: sorry about removing the correct answer. I was trying to follow the guidelines of stack overflow on follow up comments. I saw your animation on the first button. My follow up comment is referring to your second option with buttons that are included in the "if else" statement. I would like a second animation for the other buttons (If you notice, I changed the value of x and y for the non-selected buttons)

Comment: Version 11.6 (11E708)

Comment: I'm running your code, and the flag images don't change on a new game. Are you seeing that behavior?

Comment: Yes. That is the reason for my follow up

Comment: I'm apologize Luis.  I tested my code in Xcode 12beta5 and it works there, but it doesn't work at all in Xcode 11.6.  How frustrating.  SwiftUI is still pretty flakey, with some things working better in Xcode 12b5 and somethings are broken there.

Comment: Luis, I identified (pun intended) the problem in Xcode 11.6 and provided a fix.  Take a look at the updated code.

Comment: Make sure you scroll all the way to the end of the line `var countries = [...`.  It uses `.map(Flag.init)` to turn the country names into `Flag` structs.

Comment: In addition to the new version of the code using the `Identifiable` `Flag` struct, I added code to show the minimal changes necessary to make your code function correctly in Xcode 11.6.